# Transform property is not being applied in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, transform, css-transforms

Basically, I am trying to create an HTML element in Javascript when my mouse hovers over a certain element. However, I want the new HTML element that was just created to have a certain rotation/angle.
Here is my code:

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("child");
const text = element[0].getElementsByTagName("p");
let replacement;

function pulsateText() {
  replacement = document.createElement("p");
  const node = document.createTextNode("replace");
  replacement.appendChild(node);
  element[0].appendChild(replacement);
  replacement.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
  replacement.style.color = "red";
  text[0].style.opacity = "0";
}

element[0].addEventListener("mouseover", pulsateText);
element[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  replacement.remove();
  text[0].style.opacity = "1";
})
```

I have tried using the `transform` property in order to rotate the element by 90 degrees, but the element stays the same. However, the in the next line, I change the color of the element, and that works out as expected.
Any help on this problem would be appreciated...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you see when you use your browser's dev tools inspect facility as to what/where set the transform on that element?

Comment: It is basically just adding a new element `<p style="transform: rotate(90deg); color:red;>replace</p>`. So I do not understand why is it not rotating.

Comment: My question is what do you actually see in your browser's dev tools inspect facility - what is the CSS actually set as? You should be able to see exactly where the transform is being set.